# Store htmldom results in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, simple-html-dom

I try to store scraped data into my database. just to echo the result works perfectly, so the scraping is OK. But there must be an error in defining a variable and passing it to the mysql-insert. I get the message "New record created successfully". The result for the variable is empty and the date is there.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('https://www.marketwatch.com/market-data/us?mod=market-data-center');

$scriptDocument = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 

if(!empty($html)){ 

    $scriptDocument->loadHTML($html);

    libxml_clear_errors(); 

    $scriptDOMXPath = new DOMXPath($scriptDocument);
    $scriptRow = $scriptDOMXPath->query('//th[starts-with(text(), "ISSUES:")]//following::td[6]');if($scriptRow->length > 0){foreach($scriptRow as $row){echo $row->nodeValue;}} // echo result works
    $scriptRow = $scriptDOMXPath->query('//th[starts-with(text(), "ISSUES:")]//following::td[6]');if($scriptRow->length > 0){foreach($scriptRow as $row){$row->nodeValue = $nasdaq_dec;}} // defining variable does not work

};

    $host_name = '';
    $database = '';
    $user_name = '';
    $password = '';
    
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$database;", $user_name, $password);      
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `morgenroutine` (date,nasdaq_dec)
    VALUES (NOW(), '$nasdaq_dec')";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: What datatype is the column?

Comment: Its INT(11) not NULL

Comment: INT(11) is never going to store HTML. Also your `$nasdaq_dec` variable isn't defined anywhere. You're passing an empty variable.

Comment: I thought I definded the variable in the dom-line: `$row->nodeValue = $nasdaq_dec`. how should I do it instead?

Comment: No, you are defining the object `$row->nodeValue` to have the value of `$nasdaq_dec`. But `$nasdaq_dec` isn't defined anywhere , so `$row->nodeValue` is empty.

Comment: So how do I define `nasdaq_dec`?

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it! I changed the format in mysql to "text" and the line to:
`$scriptRow = $scriptDOMXPath->query('//th[starts-with(text(), "ISSUES:")]//following::td[6]');if($scriptRow->length > 0){foreach($scriptRow as $row){$nasdaq_dec = $row->nodeValue;}}`